# Choosing the right version of QT

Tags: qt, unix

On my Ubuntu 16.04, I have some packages installed (through Synaptic) that have QT version 5.5.1. And they seem to be needed by software that I have (TeXstudio, for instance).

But as a developer I am trying to use Qt 5.9.1, which I installed by downloading it from the QT website (like [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu)). But when I run qmake, it runs the wrong version. How can I choose which version I want to use?

```
$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

But I want this one:

```
~/lib/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake --version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.1 in /home/diego/lib/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib
```

I would like that all that when I'm building software or running software I have built (instead of software installed on the system) it uses 5.9.1. How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look [version of qt used for qmake](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116254/how-do-i-change-which-version-of-qt-is-used-for-qmake)

Comment: @WindyFields, I saw that, but in my Ubuntu 16.04 there is no environment variable QTDIR (if I echo it, its empty). In that post they were talking about 13.04 and 13.10, so I m guessing something has changed in the last years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run `qmake` with its full path:

`$ ~/lib/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake`

If you don't want to type full path, you could *prepend* your local Qt directory to `PATH` environment variable. In order for runtime linker to find right libraries, you can add Qt directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You could set `QTDIR` too, so tools like CMake find right Qt:

You could put following line in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export QTDIR="~/lib/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/"
export PATH="$QTDIR/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$QTDIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Comment: But will the compiled version use the right version of QT? If I run qmake with the full path, the Makefile will have the right links to the lib, so it will compile with the right libs, but what about runtime?

Comment: I'm not sure, i've been using Qt on macOS with CMake and built executables were linked to Qt by absolute paths. On Linux different versions should have different SONAMEs, so using wrong version shouldn't happen. Last, you could set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your edit. I have a question about environment variables: they are only valid for the current terminal session, right? Is there a way to set them for the entire system (even just after login, before opening any terminal or anything). Just to give it  try see if the software that depends on Qt5.5.1 still works on 5.9.1. Thanks!

Comment: @excalibur1491 Use `ldd your_binary` to see which libraries are used. Your binaries should use the correct Qt libraries, since qmake will use an RPATH when linking them. So if you use the qmake binary installed by Qt 5.9.1, your binaries should use 5.9.1 at runtime. `ldd` should confirm that. Also, if you link your binaries against 5.9.1, they cannot run against 5.8.x or lower; you'd get a crash (Qt is backwards compatible, not forwards compatible; if you compile against 5.5, you can run with 5.9. But not the other way around.)

Comment: More or less right. Each process has its own environment, and processes started from that process inherit a copy of parent process environment. If you want to set environment variables for whole login session, you could set them in `~/.profile` or `/.bashrc` files.

Comment: Neither LD_LIBRARY_PATH nor QTDIR should be used here. qmake will automatically link using correct flags and paths so the binary will find the libraries at runtime.